# BlackBerry - background image for all screen dimensions

Tags: image, blackberry, version, screen

My background bitmap size is 360 X 480.  It fits properly for the 9630 simulator, but it does not fit for the 9550 and 8520 simulators.  I need to place the image as the background and have it look right on all simulators.

What image size do I need to adjust for all simulators?

I am using the following code to display the background image:

```
private VerticalFieldManager _manager;
Bitmap backgroundBitmap1 
    = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("initloadsolution.jpg");
Bitmap background_smartBitmap 
    = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("initloadsolution_smart.jpg");   
Background bg1 
    = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(backgroundBitmap1);
_manager.setBackground(bg1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry) says:

480 × 360 pixels (Curve 89xx/Tour 9630/Bold 9650/Bold 97xx)
**360 × 480 pixels (Storm 95xx/Torch 98xx )**
480 × 320 pixels (Bold 90xx)
360 × 400 pixels (Pearl 3G)
**320 × 240 pixels (83xx/85xx/87xx/88xx/Curve 3G)**
240 × 260 pixels (71xx/81xx Series)
240 × 160 pixels (72xx/73xx Series)

Also you could [resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769755/blackberry-how-to-resize-image) or [crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682250/blackberry-cropping-image) image on runtime

Answer (score 0):

you can use blackberry image loader for all type of blackberry device

here is the link

http://www.collegemobile.com/2012/08/blackberry-image-loader/